# Trying to find out which ArcGIS Javascript API a webpage uses

Tags: javascript, arcgis, arcgis-js-api

Is it possible from looking at the Firefox firebug to find out what Javascript API a site runs on - I know its ArcGIS Javascript but need to find out what version it is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually ArcGIS apps use the API hosted on the [CDN](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jshelp/intro_accessapi.html).  If you look at the source code (in any browser), find the line below and it will tell you the API version.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://js.arcgis.com/3.8/"></script>
```